# Is it possible to perform SSL handshaking via telnet?

Tags: networking, ssl, protocols, telnet

I'm reading about how SSL works and tried to perform a handshaking with google pop3 server `pop.gmail.com 995`. I've found an example of the client hello message [there](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785811(v=ws.10).aspx). So, I connected to the gmail pop 3 server with

```
telnet pop.gmail.com 995
```

It's OK. Now I can send messages to the server. As far as I understand the first thing I need to do is to send is the client hello message. So I type the following line (I'll break lines after `\r\n` token for simplify reading):

```
ClientVersion 3,1\r\nClientRandom[32]\r\n
SessionID: None (new session)\r\n
Suggested Cipher Suites:\r\n
  TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA\r\n
  TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA\r\n
Suggested Compression Algorithm: NONE
```

Press Enter and receive the message

```
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

What's wrong? I was supposed to receive a server hello message? What do I send to receive that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The text you're trying to type in is a human-readable representation of a ClientHello message, not the real thing. The real ClientHello message is binary data, and cannot be entered through a Telnet session.

Comment: So, imagine I've established a connection via sockets (`winsock`). Is it possible to send that message with `send` function?

Comment: Yes, of course. (That's how SSL clients work internally, after all.) But you will need to implement a considerable bit of cryptography to make a connection actually go through, and to read the encrypted data.

Comment: Cryptography? I thought that client and server hello messages don't have to be encrypted and sent as just plain bytes? And after handshaking has performed they start to send encrypted data. Isn't it true?

Comment: Some of the data involved in the handshake is cryptographic in nature. Trying to use random data in those packets, or data copied from other negotiations, is unlikely to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command. After connect put your request like using telnet.

`openssl s_client -connect pop.gmail.com:995`

Comment: The question seems to be about the workings of the protocol, not just talking to an SSL server from a shell.

Comment: I think Andrey had the right answer with one the exception of missing `-quiet` flag for the openssl command. 

Like you say the question was about how to utilize the pop protocol, but since the 995 port works over TLS, that means to use the underlying pop protocol, one first needs to initialize the SSL connection.